# Handling bad lines in bigquery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am using the google.bigquery.python api in order to automatically load a dataset from a GCS bucket to Bigquery on a daily basis. I specified a schema for this dataset and it worked untill I had one day this error:

```
ERROR - {u'state': u'DONE', u'errors': [{u'reason': u'invalid', u'message': u'Invalid argument: xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com', u'location': u'File: 0 / Line:1283011 / Field:44'},
{u'reason': u'invalid', u'message': u'Invalid argument: xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com', u'location': u'File: 0 / Line:1338016 / Field:44'}, {u'reason': u'invalid', u'message': u'Too many errors encountered. Limit is: 0.'}], u'errorResult': {u'reason': u'invalid', u'message': u'Too many errors encountered. Limit is: 0.'}}
```

My question is: how can I tell bigquery to delete automatically lines which don't fit the schema?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the `bq` command line client, the option is `--max-bad-records`.  This tells BQ how many bad records to ignore before failing a load job. The default is zero. I don't recall whether setting this positive lets bad rows into the data or only ignores and suppresses the error.  You might want to manually test it.

From: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool

> --max_bad_records Type: integer Description: The maximum number of bad rows to skip before the load job is aborted and no updates are
>   performed. If this value is larger than 0, the job will succeed as
>   long as the number of bad records do not exceed this value. This is
>   useful if you would like to load files that may have bad records. The
>   default value for this parameter is 0 (all rows are required to be
>   valid).
>
> Valid Values: Any integer
>
> `Usage: bq load --max_bad_records=3 <destination_table> <data_source_uri> [<table_schema>]`

In the python API this field is called `maxBadRecords`.  You can search for `maxBadRecords` in [the python BigQuery API repo on Github](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.jobs.html#insert) and you'll see it is in the jobs API configuration for a load job.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry can't comment on Paul's answer as I have less than 50 reputations.

Re: whether setting this positive lets bad rows into the data or only ignores and suppresses the error

The bad rows will be ignored and will not go into the loaded data.